# Getting a traceback error when using pip/pip3 on Mac OS Mojave

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip

I'm trying to use pip/pip3 to install packages but I always get the same error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 143, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 318, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 102, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 256, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 209, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 218, in prepare_linked_requirement
    req.populate_link(finder, upgrade_allowed, require_hashes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 164, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 572, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 530, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 675, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 793, in _get_page
    return _get_html_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 144, in _get_html_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 525, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 396, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 503, in request
    prep.url, proxies, stream, verify, cert
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 676, in merge_environment_settings
    env_proxies = get_environ_proxies(url, no_proxy=no_proxy)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/utils.py", line 760, in get_environ_proxies
    if should_bypass_proxies(url, no_proxy=no_proxy):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/utils.py", line 744, in should_bypass_proxies
    bypass = proxy_bypass(parsed.hostname)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 2610, in proxy_bypass
    return proxy_bypass_macosx_sysconf(host)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 2587, in proxy_bypass_macosx_sysconf
    return _proxy_bypass_macosx_sysconf(host, proxy_settings)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 2573, in _proxy_bypass_macosx_sysconf
    if (hostIP >> mask) == (base >> mask):
ValueError: negative shift count
```

I'm using Homebrew on Mac OS Mojave to manage my packages and I installed Python@2(2.7) and Python(3.7) that way.

I know there's a built-in version of Python baked in Mac OS by default but I get the error even after removing the brew-installed Python packages.

I tried easy_install, the official downloaders from python.org and homebrew with always the same the error message.

Any thoughts on what could the problem be?

Comment: Not sure if it helps but 

`$ which python` gives me

`$ /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`

Comment: It is not a "traceback error". As you can see in the last line you got a `ValueError`. "traceback" refers to the stack trace of an exception.

Comment: found it, it was a proxy error. Thanks!

Comment: Can I upvote a comment ? :)

Comment: *Can I upvote a comment?* Yes. Click on the up-arrow left to the comment.